# Minimal project can't able to authenticate

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

After giving so much time towards my game authentication problem solution, I decided to go from scratch with template project.

So I downloaded Minimal project available in github and imported google-play plugin v9.30.

Just applied my application setting and try to run same project but that also can't able to authenticate.
I am getting this type of log message.

[image]

I have already updated recent version of sdk so not exist this kind of mistake.
Following image demonstrate my plugin/android data so that you become somewhat more clear.

[image]

Please guide me to solve this problem, I am available always if you have any questions regarding problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move to unity 5, all above kinds of errors are gone.
As per my thinking 4.6 version can't be work more.

Because same thing, didn't work in unity 4.6.9 and 4.6.8 but I just changed to unity 5 and all errors are gone.

Here I posted this answer because other members don't consume time in just this kind of mistake.